# Google sheet API token expiration Python

Tags: python, google-api

I'm currently working on a private script that allows for data warehouse ETL work to run. I'm saving my env secrets on a cloud vault. The problem comes when a script runs and pulls information from a private google sheet, this requires a token generated from a project on G Cloud, however, it appears the token has a limited lifespan, is there a way to get a perma-token that does not expire? (Without publishing the project)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't published the project, it will expire [every 7 days](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#:~:text=a%20refresh%20token-,expiring%20in%207%20days.,-There%20is%20currently).

To solve the issue you will need to [publish](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish) the project (you can leave it as private) by following the steps:

1. Access to console.cloud.google.com

2. Make sure that you have selected the correct project.

3. Click the 3 lines for the menu.

4. Search for "Marketplace."

5. At the top, in the search bar, type "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK," and press enter.

6. On the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK page, click Enable.

7. Create the [store listing](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/create-listing)